# Connecting to Analysis service server using python

Tags: python, ssas, mdx, windows-authentication, olap

I am trying to run MDX queries on OLAP by configuring HTTP access to Analysis Services through IIS. I used olap.xmla python library and it worked fine as long as I was using Anonymous authentication. The moment I used switched to Windows Authentication I am not able to connect using this library. I get a 401 Unauthorized error when I try to do that. The credentials are correct since I can connect to the server from MS SQL server 2008. I followed this article http://bkanuka.com/articles/python-connect-to-olap/ which worked fine for anonymous authentication. I tried passing the user pass credentials in the connect method but I guess that doesn't work for windows authentication. Any suggestions how I can do that in python.

Comment: seek for tutorial in Google please !

Comment: Which authentication methods did you configure in IIS for the HTTP access?

Comment: I was using NTLM authentication and could not figure out how to make it work. Eventually I configured basic auth too and now it works with that.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't your Linux host have to be set up to talk with the AD controller via NSS and PAM in order to use Windows authentication?

Let me know how this works, since I am going to also try implementing MDX queries on OLAP.